# Auto Increment ID in Composite key Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two class like these

```
public partial class Master
{
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int idmaster { get; set; }

       /*More fields*/
}


public partial class Detail
{
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int idmaster { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int id { get; set; }
}
```

I want to auto-increment the ID in this way:

```
|----------|-----------|
|MasterID  | ID        |
------------------------
|         1|          1|
|         1|          2|
|         1|          3|
|         1|          4|
|         2|          1|
|         2|          2|
|         2|          3|
|         2|          4|
------------------------
```

How I can do this in Entity Framework

A lot of thanks for your help

Edit: Actually I have this but I want only increment ID as I mentioned:

```
|----------|-----------|
|MasterID  | ID        |
------------------------
|         1|          1|
|         1|          2|
|         1|          3|
|         1|          4|
|         2|          5|
|         2|          6|
|         2|          7|
|         2|          8|
------------------------
```

I know that I can do via code but I wanted to know if there are another way to do it.

Comment: can be done via code

Comment: what is wrong with that ?  is your key set properly in the database ?

Comment: I think this is utterly useless. It always spells trouble if you start using meaningful ID values. For one: you will never be able to change their order if you'd ever want it (well, it's not trivial at all). If you need to display any sequence numbers, generate them at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, use a trigger in your database.

```
-- TSQL in SQL Server 2008+
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Detail_autoidentity ON Detail
INSTEAD OF
INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Detail(idmaster, id) 
  SELECT inserted.idmaster, isnull((SELECT max(id) FROM Detail WHERE idmaster = inserted.idmaster), 0) +  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idmaster ORDER BY id) 
FROM inserted
END
--I Love this one, it work for multiline insert. May need a lock for multiuser, I'm not sure.
```